# How to change the height of d3 observable notebook embed

Tags: d3.js

so I understand that I can change the fixed width instead of a responsive width, by importing Library, then re-assigning the width value. But I also want to change the height and including `,height: 500` doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong and what other way is there to embed the d3 observable notebook chart with customizable width and height without using an iframe?

```
<div class="chart"></div>
<p>Credit: <a href="https://observablehq.com/@tripletk/mmcovid19-confirmedcases">Myanmar COVID-19 Total Lab
        Confirmed Cases by Timmy Kyaw</a></p>

<script type="module">
    import {
        Runtime,
        Inspector,
        Library
    } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/runtime@4/dist/runtime.js";

    const runtime = new Runtime(Object.assign(new Library, {
        width: 500
    }));
    import define from "https://api.observablehq.com/d/1adf72a9a09835c3.js?v=3";
    const main = runtime.module(define, name => {
        if (name === "chart") return Inspector.into(".chart")();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width works differently than height in Observable notebooks. You’ve already found how to change width: it’s a reactive variable that you can override with a constant like you’re doing; by default it uses with width of the document body.

For height, or any other value you want to inject like `data` or `zipCode`, you should use `main.redefine("height", 500)`. (I’m using 200 in the example below, just change it to 500.)

```html
<div class="chart"></div>
<p>Credit: <a href="https://observablehq.com/@tripletk/mmcovid19-confirmedcases">
Myanmar COVID-19 Total Lab Confirmed Cases by Timmy Kyaw</a></p>

<script type="module">
    import {
        Runtime,
        Inspector,
        Library
    } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/runtime@4/dist/runtime.js";

    const runtime = new Runtime(Object.assign(new Library, {
        width: 500
    }));
    import define from "https://api.observablehq.com/d/1adf72a9a09835c3.js?v=3";
    const main = runtime.module(define, name => {
        if (name === "chart") return Inspector.into(".chart")();
    });
    main.redefine("height", 200)
</script>
```

Often it’s useful to make the figure fill an enclosing div instead of hardcoding a width and height: see [this example](https://github.com/observablehq/examples/blob/main/custom-fluid-width-and-height/index.html) of that approach. Also for reference, [the docs](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/downloading-and-embedding-notebooks) have more information about both the `redefine` and `new Library` techniques.